# Is '⚡' an emoji?

Tags: meaning, technology, emoticons

Me and a few other people debated over this for a while. I wanted to see what you guys thought it was.

The debate started here: http://mcforums.org/threads/208/#post-2031

Comment: Every symbol can be treated as an Emoji depending on where and how you use it. Also, Emojis tend to transcend boundaries and are not restricted to a particular language. I think this question is better asked in UX or Graphic Design SE, provided those sites tolerate these type of questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Emojis are not English Language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the Unicode symbol U+26A1: HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN.

To be considered an emoji, it must be [a small digital image or icon used to express an idea or emotion in electronic communication](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emoji). As long as it is used to express danger, electricity, or lightning, it can be considered an emoji according to the [Unicode website](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#26a1).